# Php - make site multilangue with minumum changes of code

Tags: php, multilingual, translate

I have site coded in php. It uses constructions like

```
print "$x $y at {$SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}";
```

Now I want to make my site multilanguage but I want to use minimum changes in code, to be able to write something like

```
//my translation array - I select all such lines in one place
//IMPORTANT: $x, $y and $SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] are not defined yet. 
//This templates should be defined before the code.
$lang = array(
    'message'=>'$x $y at {$SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}';
);
translate('message');
```

which will translate my site.

This is more PSEUDO CODE that illustrate my idea:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

///////////////////////translation
//my translation array. 
//IMPORTANT: $x, $y and $SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] are not defined yet.
//This templates should be defined before the code.

$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=='localhost';

$lang = array(
    'message'=>"$x $y at {$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}",
);

function translate($v){
    //hmmm. All magic is doing here - but I do not know how :)
    global $lang;
    $tpl = $lang[$v];
    print $tpl;
    eval("\$tpl = \"$tpl\";");
    print $tpl;
}


////////////////////////start main work
$x = 'hello';
$y = 'world';

print $lang['message'];
translate("message");
//I want to print "hello world at localhost";

$y = 'world2';

translate("message");
//I want to print "hello world2 at localhost";

$lang['message'] = 'only $x';
translate("message");
//I want to print "only hello";

?>
```

But it does not work :)

How is it possible to implement such approach?

Comment: How about `gettext` ?

Comment: How about 'want to use minimum changes in code, to be able to write something like'?

Comment: use google translate for website

Comment: BTW: You really dont need $lang as a global

Comment: *But it does not work* - Please clearly explain what *does't* work..

Comment: _Please clearly explain what does't work_ -  The problem is that I want to use variables in language translation like "$x $y at {$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}", but before the variables $x and $y are described.

Answer (score 0):

Not very nice, but does what you want with minimal initial effort:

```
$lang = array(
    'en'=>"$x $y at {$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}",
    'it'=>"$x $y italiano {$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}",
    // whatever other language
);

function translate($v, array $lang){
    if (array_key_exists($v, $lang)) {
        return $lang[$v];
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Invalid language');
    }
}

echo translate('it', $lang);
```

Comment: The problem is that I want to use language translation like `"$x $y at {$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}",` before the variables $x and $y are described.

Answer (score 0):

I 'd say that using an inline php array for translations, as you propose, would result in a big mess, in case you want to extend your translations functionality.

A basic approach that I have used is the following:

1)Persist a 'Translations' table, which will look sth like:

```
Keyword | English | German | ...
hello   | hello   | hallo  | ...
```

2) Then on page load, fetch them from the DB and create an array of translations, like so:

```
$translate = array(
    'hello'=> array ("English"=>"hello", "German"=>"hallo"),
    'next_translation'=> array ("English"=>"...", "German"=>"..."),
    ....
);
```

3) Maintain a $lang variable with the current language, i.e "English".

4) So whenever you need to translate sth, you just need the key and language var:

```
$translate[$keyword][$lang];
```

Comment: I know how to generate $translate[$keyword][$lang]. But the question was hot to use it not for word-by-word translation, but for more difficult things like `$translate[$keyword][$lang] = "$x $y at {$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}"`

Comment: And I want to use such templates before the variables $x and $y are described.